# Django - How to sort Post model by votes?

Tags: django, sorting, django-models

I'm trying to sort posts in views.py with the greatest number of votes at the very top to the least at the bottom.

Here's what I have so far:

Post model in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("HeadLine", max_length=256, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=256,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    comments = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def count_votes(self):
        self.votes = Vote.objects.filter(post = self).count()

    @property
    def sort_by_votes(self):
        return Vote.objects.filter(post = self).count()

    def count_comments(self):
        self.comments = Comment.objects.filter(post = self).count()
```

list of posts in views.py

```
 def NewPostListView(request):

    posts = sorted(Post.objects.all(), key=lambda p: p.sort_by_votes, reverse = True)
    for post in posts:
        post.count_votes()
        print(post)
        post.count_comments()
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request,'postlist.html', context)
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('count_votes')`, but I get a "Cannot resolve keyword" error.  So far, using the `sorted()` seems to work, but sometimes the upvote value isn't correct.  How can I get a QuerySet to sort posts by votes?

Comment: If the votes fields can be more then one  use **Sum()**: `Post.objects.values("creator").annotate(Count('creator')),sum_votes=Sum('votes')).order_by('sum_votes')`.

Comment: To simple ordering by descending add **min sign "-"** :  Post.objects.order_by('-votes').

Answer (score 2):

Since your function `count_votes` is callig a model named `Votes` i think that in your `Post` model you have a foreign key to the `Votes` model or vice versa. If not i suggest to make it.

Assuming this, you can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count
votes = Post.objects.annotate(count_votes=Count('votes')).order_by('count_votes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('votes')`?

`count_votes` is the method of `Post`, not an attribute. However, `votes` is.

Comment: He wants the greatest number first, so ```order_by('-votes')``` is better

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set votes as your default ordering for the Post model you can set the ordering attribute under Post class Meta

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = "-votes"
```

Note the negative as you want to sort in descending order (greatest value on top)